# Can I add Dart Web UI bindings to DOM elements created in code?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

In the Dart Web UI package, it is possible to create bindings using the `{{}}` or `bind-value` syntax. Is this also possible, when DOM elements are created in code?

Something like

```dart
new Element.html('<div>Value: {{str}}</div>');
```

and

```dart
new Element.html('<input type="text" bind-value="str">');
```

binding an event to `str`, without manually piecing the strings together?

---

**Note**: this question was asked earlier today, but was deleted before it was answered, but I wanted to know the answer, so I'm reposting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer, no.

The bindings need to be processed by the `dwc` transformer, which converts Web Components and MDV code into "vanilla" Dart and HTML (suitable for compilation to "vanilla" JavaScript).

Generally, you should use `<template>` tags to instantiate new elements.

An alternative is to wrap these bits of text inside a custom element, which you can transform with `dwc` and instantiate manually.